# JQuery Parent/Child Ajax load

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

The page Parent.htm contains a div which loads Child.htm via ajax request.

Parent.htm includes an script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myinput.js" />"></script>
```

The myinput.js includes a widget which names myInput. At the end of widget it has a function which add this widget to some inputs as follow:

```
(function($) {
$.fn.myInput= function(options) {
 .....................
 ....................

$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('Function called');
    $("input[lang='fa']").myInput();
});
```

The child.htm is very simple as:

```
<input name="test" lang="fa">
```

**The child.html does not include the script in it.**

When I run parent.htm the child.htm loads and the alert message popups up but the widget is not applied.

When I add below line to child.html the widget works.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[lang='fa']").myInput();
});
```

It shows that the jQuery document ready is not applied to child.html ! If it is true, why the alert box works correctly pop ups!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alert message shows because it's not dependent on the dynamically loaded content (child.html).  The alert shows as soon as the document is ready, regardless of any other events:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('Function called');
    // other code
});
```

The reason the plugin isn't applied is because even though the document (parent.html) is ready, the dynamic content hasn't loaded yet:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // other code
    $("input[lang='fa']").myInput();
});
```

The code isn't waiting for AJAX calls to load other content, the document is "ready" before those calls are made and certainly before the responses to those calls are received.  Thus, at the time that code runs, this selector doesn't find the elements you're loading dynamically:

```
$("input[lang='fa']")
```

While you can get away with deferred binding on events to get around this issue, with plugins that's not the case because the content needs to be present in the DOM for a plugin to work.  So what you need to do is initialize the plugin a second time on elements loaded via AJAX when that AJAX call succeeds.  For example:

```
$("#someDiv").load("child.html", function() {
    $("#someDiv input[lang='fa']").myInput();
});
```

While the code you already have will initialize the plugin for any matched elements in parent.html, this code will be called once child.html has been loaded and initialize the plugin for any matches elements specifically in that dynamically loaded content.